# do(onNext:) called twice when table view row is selected

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, rx-swift

I'm facing a problem when selecting the table view row on RxSwift. For details, the code on the do(onNext:) function is called twice, thus lead to the navigation pushed twice too. Here is my code in the viewModel, please help me resolve it. Thanks so much.

```
struct Input {
    let loadTrigger: Driver<String>
    let searchTrigger: Driver<String>
    let selectMealTrigger: Driver<IndexPath>
}

struct Output {
    let mealList: Driver<[Meal]>
    let selectedMeal: Driver<Meal>
}

func transform(_ input: HomeViewModel.Input) -> HomeViewModel.Output {
    let popularMeals = input.loadTrigger
        .flatMap { _ in
            return self.useCase.getMealList()
            .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: [])
    }

    let mealSearchList = input.searchTrigger
        .flatMap { text in
            return self.useCase.getMealSearchList(mealName: text)
            .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: [])
    }

    let mealList = Observable.of(mealSearchList.asObservable(), popularMeals.asObservable()).merge().asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: [])

    let selectedMeal = input.selectMealTrigger
        .withLatestFrom(mealList) { $1[$0.row] }
        .do(onNext: { meal in
            self.navigator.toMealDetail(meal: meal)
        })

    return Output(mealList: mealList, selectedMeal: selectedMeal)
}
```

Edit: Here's the implemetation on the ViewController:

```
func bindViewModel() {
    self.tableView.delegate = nil
    self.tableView.dataSource = nil
    let emptyTrigger = searchBar
    .rx.text.orEmpty
    .filter { $0.isEmpty }
    .throttle(0.1, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
    .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: "")

    let loadMealTrigger = Observable
    .of(emptyTrigger.asObservable(), Observable.just(("")))
    .merge()
    .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: "")

    let searchTrigger = searchBar.rx.text.orEmpty.asDriver()
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .filter {!$0.isEmpty }
    .throttle(0.1)

    let selectMealTrigger = tableView.rx.itemSelected.asDriver()

    let input = HomeViewModel.Input(
        loadTrigger: loadMealTrigger,
        searchTrigger: searchTrigger,
        selectMealTrigger: selectMealTrigger
    )

    let output = viewModel.transform(input)

        output.mealList
            .drive(tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: MealCell.cellIdentifier)) { index, meal, cell in
                let mealCell = cell as! MealCell
                mealCell.meal = meal
    }
    .disposed(by: bag)

    output.selectedMeal
    .drive()
    .disposed(by: bag)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, is this RxSwift? 
If so, the .do(onNext:) operator provides side effects when you receive a new event via a subscription; Therefore, two "reactions" will happen when a table row is tapped: 1. subscription method and 2. .do(onNext:) event. Unfortunately, I do not have any further insight into your code, so there may be other stuff creating that error aswell.
Good luck!

Comment: Yes, I'm working on RxSwift and Clean Architecture. I've just attached my view controller code above. Please checkout. Thanks